# Cambiar Valores de ComboBox de forma Dinámica

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

Saludos a toda la comunidad:
Estoy haciendo que un combobox cambie de forma automática segun la selección de un radiobutton, pero no me sale aún, este es el código:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk   
def sel():
   selection ="Tu estas selecionando: "+str(var.get())
   label.config(text = selection) 

root = Tk()           
var  = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Opcion 1", variable=var, value=1,command=sel)
R1.pack( anchor = W )

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Opcion 2", variable=var, value=2,command=sel)
R2.pack( anchor = W )

R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Opcion 3", variable=var, value=3,command=sel)
R3.pack( anchor = W )

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
v=["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril"]
c=["Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves"]
m=["1","2","3","4"]
comboExample = ttk.Combobox(root,values=v)
r=str(var.get())
if r=="1" :
  comboExample = ttk.Combobox(root,values=v)
if r=="2" :
  comboExample = ttk.Combobox(root,values=c)
if r=="3" :
  comboExample = ttk.Combobox(root,values=m)
comboExample.pack()                            
root.mainloop()
```

Gracias por su atención y buenas noches:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La actualización del `Combobox` debe hacerse cada vez que se selecciona un nuevo `Checkbutton`. Con tu código simplemente creas un `Combobox` con unos valores determinados al iniciar la app, ese condicional no se vuelve a ejecutar nunca más.

Para conseguir lo que quieres debes usar la callback asociada a los checksbuttons, `sel`, para modificar las opciones cada vez que un botón se seleccione. Para modificar los valores usa el atributo `values` simplemente, no crees una nueva instancia del widget como intentabas originalmente:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



v = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril"]
c = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves"]
m = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

def sel():
    r = str(var.get())
    selection = "Tu estas selecionando: " + r
    label.config(text=selection)

    if r == "1" :
        combo_box['values'] = v
    elif r == "2" :
        combo_box['values'] = c
    elif r == "3" :
        combo_box['values'] = m

root = tk.Tk()  

var  = tk.IntVar()
r1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Opcion 1", variable=var, value=1, command=sel)
r1.pack(anchor=tk.W )

r2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Opcion 2", variable=var, value=2, command=sel)
r2.pack(anchor=tk.W)

r3 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Opcion 3", variable=var, value=3, command=sel)
r3.pack(anchor=tk.W)

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

combo_box = ttk.Combobox(root, values=v)
combo_box.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias. Sirvió de mucho. Es la forma correcta. De razon me hacia un circulo vicioso en el combo, con tu explicación lo entendi. Y con la lectura del código mucho mejor. Graciass

Comment: De nada Ronald, si tienes alguna duda al respecto solo comenta. Una duda mía, me acabo de dar cuenta que etiquetas la pregunta como `python 2.x` pero el código que muestras es para Python 3.x ¿Es un error en el etiquetado? Más que nada es para no confundir a otros usuarios dado que ni tu código ni el mío es ejecutable en Python 2 por los imports.

Comment: Hummm. Esque la verdad tengo po defecto el python 2.7.12. Que viene instalado con Arcgis. Y estoy utilizando el pycharm 2019.1.community. Por eso le puse la etiqueta 2.x.